# A valid option to satisfy the declaration could not be found in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using **serverless** framework and using **bitbucket-pipeline** to configure **CI/CD**.

I have the following configuration in the `serverless.yml` file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: ${opt:region, ${env:AWS_REGION, 'ap-south-1'}}
  memorySize: ${opt:memory, ${env:MEMORY_SIZE, 512}}tracing:
  apiGateway: ${env:TRACING_API_GATEWAY, true}
```

I want to be able to pass the variables from the `CLI` as well as `environment variables`.

I have set up environment variable for `AWS_REGION` in the bitbucket pipeline variables but not for `MEMORY_SIZE` as want to use the default value.

**But this gives error while running the pipeline.**

```
Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid option to satisfy the declaration 'opt:region,ap-south-1' could not be found.

Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:MEMORY_SIZE,512' could not be found.


Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:TRACING_API_GATEWAY,true' could not be found.
```

Answer (score -1):

First, those are warnings not errors. A Serverless error would be something like:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${opt:stage}. Please make sure the value of the property is a string.
```

This specific error happens because in the `custom` tag I've declared: `var: ${opt:stage}-something` which should be changed like:

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'local'}

custom:
  var: ${self:provider.stage}-something
```

I think in your case, you need to update region like this:

```
region: ${opt:region, env:AWS_REGION, 'ap-south-1'}
```

I couldn't reproduce the last warning though but I reckon ENV variables should be defined in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` (or similar CI pipeline YAML) under `args` or `variables` and then they can be accessed using `${env:VAR}`.